# Could Not Fetch GradleBuild using Gradle Buildship extension

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin

Every time I try to import my project, which I have imported before a few months ago with no problem, I get the following error:
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-bin.zip'.
I get this for every version I select, and I even tried to do a manual install of Gradle and point there but I get the same error. Any ideas for fixes?
(For reference, I am running STS 4)